# What is the best way to add time portion in java.util.Date

Tags: java

I want to add current timestamp to the java.util.Date, **Here i tried with below code Is this Correct approach? or do we have any other way to achieve this?**,What is the best way to Add time portion in util Date.

```
public class Test {

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws ParseException
   */
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws ParseException {

    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final Date date = format.parse("2017-09-14"); //This One I will get from DB

    builder.append(format.format(date));
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("'T'HH:mm:ss");
    builder.append(format.format(new Date())); //Appending Time portion
    System.out.println("builder-->" + builder);
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    //Finally Converted to String format
    System.out.println(format.format(format.parse(builder.toString())));
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of your code? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Hi Mark baijens, It is working what i expected, am asking, is this way is correct?, or do we have any other way to achieve this.

Comment: You might want to use the new `java.time` package unless you're working pre-Java8. The `Date` class is a horrible thing.

Comment: is correct? ... good question. Generally we all are migrating to java8 LocalDateTime and look at withXxxxx methods

Comment: Well Jacek Cz, currently we are stick with java 1.7 :(

Comment: Joda DateTime (precursor of java8 solution). Very natural date/time arithmetic

Comment: Or the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). I believe that's generally recommended over Joda Time these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the java.util.Calendar object to add the time needed

```
Calendar dateCal = Calendar.getInstance();
dateCal.setTime(date);

Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();
currentCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()); 

dateCal.set(Calendar.HOUR, currentCal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
dateCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, currentCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

and then you have the nice DateFormat to print out in any format you want

Comment: How can we set, the hours and Minutes,i want to set these are current system hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: @Prasad updated answer, you could use a current Calendar to get/set time portion of a day